# regex for [2,4,p^t,2p^t] where p is prime and t is any positive integer

Tags: math, cryptography, rsa, number-theory

i was learning the cryptography where i got the assignment for building the primitive root for the given number so before doing the calculation i need to check that a number must be any of these form

```
[2,4,p^t,2p^t]
```

is their any regex that can check that??
if not then is their any way i can check that number is built up from this form??

Comment: Regexs look at character sequences, so a regex could be matched against the textual forms, in say base 10, of 2 and 4 quite easily. As for the other two forms, I doubt there is any practical regex you can use. For non-regex solutions, it's computationally easy to take a big integer, determine if it is an integer power of another integer, and recover the power and root. I'm sure there is a dup for that somewhere on SO for that, I'll try to find it. After that, you can test whether the root is prime using Miller-Rabin.

Comment: "Is there *any* regex" is an interesting question ... I don't know what your instructor intended, but it occurs to me that if a number is written in base p, then 1, 10, 100, 1000, ... etc. are powers of p, and "a regex" would be `10*` for such a number.